# tslint - CI build fail that got "Could not find implementations" and "Severity for rule 'curly not found"

Tags: travis-ci, tslint

[The project](https://github.com/FoXZilla/short-night) is passing `npm run tslint` in my Macbook, but it fails in CI.

CI build detail see: https://travis-ci.org/FoXZilla/short-night/builds/468354760

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `package.json` lists `ts-lint`, which is an old copy of `tslint`. Remove that and it should work.

Explanation: the rules it's complaining are missing were added in versions of `tslint` added after `ts-lint` was published. Locally you might be resolving to the correct package, but in CI you probably aren't.

Comment: Great! It's passed when I removed `ts-lint` in package.json and using `npm ci` in CI! https://github.com/FoXZilla/short-night/compare/c97af95c4e98602f60450558f7cac97412449bea..855e3c123ef65f1a4fba8ddf7b804e069edc15bf